# scp hangs in->out and works normally out->in

Tags: networking, 18.04, scp

The trouble machine is called **gpu17**

- ssh works correctly
- scp in another machine to download a file, or upload a file works correctly
- ping has 100% packet loss
- have rebooted, no change
- Nothing seems to be blocking in the firewall

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

- No ports seems to be blocked

```
$ nmap -P0  88.99.253.27
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-02-03 09:46 CET
Nmap scan report for gpu17 (88.99.253.27)
Host is up (0.00053s latency).
Not shown: 999 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

$ sudo nmap -P0 -sU 88.99.253.27
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-02-03 10:01 CET
Nmap scan report for gpu17 (88.99.253.27)
Host is up.
All 1000 scanned ports on gpu17 (88.99.253.27) are open|filtered

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 201.37 seconds
```

- scp ran in **gpu17** always times out

```
$ scp -v rabo2.txt gpu10:/home/dario/rabo4.txt
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host gpu10, user (unspecified), command scp -v -t /home/dario/rabo4.txt
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gpu10 [46.4.90.217] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 46.4.90.217 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host gpu10 port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection

$ scp -v gpu10:/home/dario/rabo4.txt .
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host gpu10, user (unspecified), command scp -v -f /home/dario/rabo4.txt
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gpu10 [46.4.90.217] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 46.4.90.217 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host gpu10 port 22: Connection timed out
```

- `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` has nothing new during those 2 commands

What else should I try to diagnose or fix this issue?

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: Added it, sorry and thanks